JPA: Error creating bean with name 'calendarioTurnosController' defined in file
As i'm trying to deploy my applicattion on my Tomcat 9.0 server I'm getting the next error on deployment
19-Apr-2024 10:19:54.168 INFO [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time. 
19-Apr-2024 10:20:21.261 SEVERE [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web application archive [C:\Program Files\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\uniformidad.war]     java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:686)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:658)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:661)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1025)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1919)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:826)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:476)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1668)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:314)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:114)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1098)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1301)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1283)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/uniformidad]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:419)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:186)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:683)
        ... 25 more 
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'calendarioTurnosController' defined in file [C:\Program Files\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\uniformidad\WEB-INF\classes\com\michelin\uniformidad\controller\uniformidad\CalendarioTurnosController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'uniformidadService' defined in file [C:\Program Files\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\uniformidad\WEB-INF\classes\com\michelin\uniformidad\service\uniformidad\UniformidadService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 10; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'calendarioTurnosRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.michelin.uniformidad.model.tablasove.CalendarioTurnosEntity
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:769)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:218)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1341)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1187)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:845)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:744)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:391)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:151)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:131)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:91)
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4904)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
        ... 26 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'uniformidadService' defined in file [C:\Program Files\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\uniformidad\WEB-INF\classes\com\michelin\uniformidad\service\uniformidad\UniformidadService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 10; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'calendarioTurnosRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.michelin.uniformidad.model.tablasove.CalendarioTurnosEntity 
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:769)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:218)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1341)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1187)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1251)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1171)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760)
        ... 48 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'calendarioTurnosRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.michelin.uniformidad.model.tablasove.CalendarioTurnosEntity 
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1778)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1251)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1171)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760)
        ... 62 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.michelin.uniformidad.model.tablasove.CalendarioTurnosEntity
        at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:552)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:74)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:66)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:201)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:151)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:134)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:65)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:305)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:297)
        at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:211)
        at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:94)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:300)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:121)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774)
        ... 73 more 
19-Apr-2024 10:20:21.277 INFO [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [C:\Program Files\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\uniformidad.war] has finished in [42,141] ms

The mistake seems obvious, but i have been searching where did i fail and i can´t find it.
I can deploy this same app in my localhost server.
Here you have:
Entity
package com.michelin.uniformidad.model.tablasove;

import lombok.*;

import javax.persistence.*;

/**
 * Clase CalendarioTurnosEntity que representa la entidad CalendarioTurnos en la base de datos.
 *
 * @Entity indica que esta clase es una entidad.
 * @Table(name = "calendario_turnos", catalog="dbo") especifica el nombre de la tabla y el catálogo en la base de datos.
 */
@Entity
@Builder
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name="calendario_equipos")
public class CalendarioTurnosEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "FechaTurno")
    private String fechaTurno;

    @Column(name = "area_uno")
    private String area_uno;
    @Column(name = "area_dos")
    private String area_dos;
    @Column(name = "area_tres")
    private String area_tres;

    private String a;
    private String b;
    private String c;

    private String dia;


}


Repository
package com.michelin.uniformidad.repository.tablasove;

import com.michelin.uniformidad.dto.uniformidad.CalendarioTurnosDto;
import com.michelin.uniformidad.model.tablasove.CalendarioTurnosEntity;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Repositorio CalendarioTurnosRepository para interactuar con la base de datos.
 *
 * @Repository indica que esta interfaz es un repositorio.
 * JpaRepository proporciona métodos para las operaciones CRUD.
 */
public interface CalendarioTurnosRepository extends JpaRepository<CalendarioTurnosEntity, Integer> {

    /**
     * Busca los turnos del calendario para el año especificado.
     *
     * @param year Año para el que se buscan los turnos.
     * @return Lista de CalendarioTurnosDto con los datos de los turnos.
     */
    @Query(value = "SELECT PivotTable.Dia, PivotTable.A, PivotTable.B, PivotTable.C, \n" +
            "CASE WHEN (PivotTable.A=0 and PivotTable.B = 0 And PivotTable.C = 0) Then 'Red' WHEN (PivotTable.A=0 or PivotTable.B = 0 or PivotTable.C = 0) Then 'Yellow' else 'White' END AS Color \n" +
            "From \n" +
            "(SELECT SUBSTRING(FechaTurno, 5, 4) AS Dia, SUBSTRING(FechaTurno, 9, 11) AS Turno, area_uno FROM calendario_equipos WHERE (SUBSTRING(FechaTurno, 1, 4) = ?1)) AS SourceTable\n" +
            "PIVOT (min(area_uno) For Turno in ([A], [B], [C])) AS PivotTable", nativeQuery = true)
    List<CalendarioTurnosDto> searchCalendarioTurnos0(Integer year);

    /**
     * Actualiza el turno en el calendario para la fecha especificada.
     *
     * @param activo Estado del turno.
     * @param fechaTurno Fecha del turno.
     * @return Número de filas afectadas.
     */
    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query(value="/*/", nativeQuery = true)
    Integer updateCalendarioTurnos0(String activo, String fechaTurno);
    
    /**
     * Selecciona el turno para la fecha especificada.
     *
     * @param fechaTurno Fecha del turno.
     * @return Estado del turno.
     */
    @Query(value="/*/", nativeQuery = true)
    String selectTurno0(String fechaTurno);

    /**
     * Inserta los turnos para el año especificado.
     *
     * @param fechaTurno Fecha del turno.
     * @param Activo Estado del primer turno.
     * @param activo2 Estado del segundo turno.
     * @param activo3 Estado del tercer turno.
     */
    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query (value = "/*/", nativeQuery = true)
    void insertTurnosAnyo(String fechaTurno, String Activo, String activo2, String activo3);

}


DataSource
package com.michelin.uniformidad.configuration;

import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

/**
 * Configuración de la fuente de datos TablasOve.
 *
 * @Configuration indica que esta clase tiene métodos @Bean que proporcionan componentes de la aplicación.
 * @EnableTransactionManagement habilita la gestión de transacciones de Spring.
 * @EnableJpaRepositories habilita la creación de repositorios JPA.
 */
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.michelin.uniformidad.repository.tablasove",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "tablasOveEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef= "tablasOveTransactionManager")
public class TablasOveDataSourceConfiguration {

    /**
     * Método para configurar las propiedades de la fuente de datos TablasOve.
     *
     * @return las propiedades de la fuente de datos TablasOve.
     */
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.tablasove")
    public DataSourceProperties tablasOveDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    /**
     * Método para configurar la fuente de datos TablasOve.
     *
     * @return la fuente de datos TablasOve.
     */
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix= "spring.datasource.tablasove.configuration")
    public DataSource tablasOveDataSource() {
        return tablasOveDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder()
                .type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
    }

    /**
     * Método para configurar el EntityManagerFactory para la fuente de datos TablasOve.
     *
     * @param builder el constructor del EntityManagerFactory.
     * @return el EntityManagerFactory para la fuente de datos TablasOve.
     */
    @Bean(name = "tablasOveEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean tablasOveEntityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(tablasOveDataSource())
                .packages("com.michelin.uniformidad.model.tablasove")
                .build();
    }

    /**
     * Método para configurar el gestor de transacciones para la fuente de datos TablasOve.
     *
     * @param tablasOveEntityManagerFactory el EntityManagerFactory para la fuente de datos TablasOve.
     * @return el gestor de transacciones para la fuente de datos TablasOve.
     */
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager tablasOveTransactionManager(
            final @Qualifier("tablasOveEntityManagerFactory") LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean tablasOveEntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(tablasOveEntityManagerFactory.getObject());
    }
}


Controller
package com.michelin.uniformidad.controller.tablasOve;

import com.michelin.uniformidad.dto.uniformidad.CalendarioTurnosDto;
import com.michelin.uniformidad.model.tablasove.CalendarioTurnosEntity;
import com.michelin.uniformidad.service.tablasOve.TablasOveService;
import com.michelin.uniformidad.service.uniformidad.UniformidadService;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Month;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

/**
 * Controlador para la gestión de los turnos del calendario.
 *
 * @RestController indica que esta clase es un controlador REST.
 * @RequestMapping("/api/calendarioturnos") mapea las solicitudes HTTP a los métodos de esta clase.
 */
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/calendarioturnos")
public class CalendarioTurnosController {
    /**
     * Servicio para interactuar con los datos de uniformidad.
     */
    private final TablasOveService tablasOveService;

    /**
     * Constructor de la clase.
     *
     * @param tablasOveService servicio para interactuar con los datos de uniformidad.
     */
    public CalendarioTurnosController(TablasOveService tablasOveService) {
        this.tablasOveService = tablasOveService;
    }

    /**
     * Este método se utiliza para buscar los turnos para un año y área dados. Si no se encuentran turnos,
     * inserta un nuevo año y luego recupera los turnos. Está mapeado a una solicitud GET en la ruta "/api/calendarioturnos".
     * @param year año del calendario.
     * @param area área del calendario.
     * @return lista de turnos del calendario.
     */
    @GetMapping(value = "")
    public List<CalendarioTurnosDto> findCalendarioTurnos(@RequestParam("year") Integer year, @RequestParam("area") Integer area) {
        List<CalendarioTurnosDto> ctd = tablasOveService.searchCalendarioTurnos(year, area);
        if(ctd == null || ctd.isEmpty()){
            insertNuevoAnyo(year);
            ctd = tablasOveService.searchCalendarioTurnos(year,area);
        }
        return ctd;
    }
    /**
     * Este método se utiliza para actualizar los turnos para un identificador de turno y área dados. Cambia el estado
     * activo del turno y devuelve el número de turnos actualizados. Está mapeado a una solicitud PATCH en la ruta "/api/calendarioturnos/update-turno".
     * @param turno turno a actualizar.
     * @param area área del calendario.
     * @return número de turnos actualizados.
     */
    @PatchMapping(value = "/update-turno")
    public Integer findCalendarioTurnos(@RequestParam("turno") String turno, @RequestParam("area") Integer area) {
        String activo = tablasOveService.selectTurno(turno, area);
        if(activo.equals("0"))
            activo = "1";
        else activo = "0";
        Integer ctd = tablasOveService.updateCalendarioTurnos(turno, activo, area);
        return ctd;
    }
    /**
     * Este método se utiliza para insertar un nuevo año en el calendario. Genera una lista de fechas para
     * todo el año y las inserta en la base de datos. Este método no está mapeado a ninguna solicitud HTTP, por lo que solo se puede llamar internamente dentro de la clase.
     * @param year año a insertar.
     */
    public void insertNuevoAnyo(Integer year){
        LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of(year, Month.JANUARY, 1);
        LocalDate endDate = ld.plusYears(1);

        List<LocalDate> allDays = new ArrayList<>(365);
        while (ld.isBefore(endDate)) {
            allDays.add(ld);
            ld = ld.plusDays(1);
        }
        DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd");
        List<String> formatsa = allDays.stream().map(value -> value.format(format)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<String> formatsb = allDays.stream().map(value -> value.format(format)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<String> formatsc = allDays.stream().map(value -> value.format(format)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        List<String> allFormat = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int x = 0; x<formatsa.size() ; x++){
            formatsa.set(x, formatsa.get(x) + "A") ;
        }
        for (int z = 0; z<formatsb.size() ; z++){
            formatsb.set(z, formatsb.get(z) + "B") ;
        }
        for (int y = 0; y<formatsc.size() ; y++){
            formatsc.set(y, formatsc.get(y) + "C") ;
        }
        allFormat.addAll(formatsa);
        allFormat.addAll(formatsb);
        allFormat.addAll(formatsc);
        Collections.sort(allFormat);

        for(int p = 0; p<allFormat.size(); p++){
            CalendarioTurnosEntity cte = new CalendarioTurnosEntity();
            cte.setFechaTurno(allFormat.get(p));
            cte.setArea_uno("1");
            cte.setArea_dos("1");
            cte.setArea_tres("1");
            tablasOveService.insertTurnoAnyo(cte);
        }

    }

}


Ill appreciate any hint you can give me!
I'm expecting to resolve the issue

Let me guess, using Spring Boot 3, and tried to "fix" compilation errors due to javax.persistence by adding dependencies.

@M.Deinum not really, my compilation went fine, and I had no problems with other entities.

Are you referencing it from a different entity? You have multiple entitymanagers (at least judging from your configuration). Make sure that the other @EnableJpaRepositories don't scan the same packages (else they will try to create an instance as well without the proper meta-data because they operate on different packages).

@M.Deinum thank you, after researching a bit more i have "disabled" this module and i realized that im having two different datasources with the same name in two different instances, ill solve it asap. have a nice day!

After researching a bit more i have "disabled" this module and i realized that im having two different datasources with the same name in two different instances, ill solve it asap.
